# rails sort collection by custom method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method which takes ID of project and find all payments, do the math and the output is percentage of success (target amount vs collected)

```
def projectCollectedMoneyPerc(id)
    @project= Project.find(id)
    @collected = Payment.where('project_id = ? and confirmed = true', @project.id)
    @col = @collected.sum(:amount)

    @perc = ((@col.to_f / @project.amount) * 100).round(0)
end
```

now I need to find projects which have most % success. My idea was to call this method by sort_by but I have no idea how to put ID from collection to this sort

my collection is simple

```
@projects=Project.where('enabled = true and enddate > ?', Time.now)
```

thanks

Comment: You should read a good book about Rails! You are definitely missing out the point of `has_many`, `@collected` will usually never be `nil`, etc.

Comment: I have model where project has_many payments and payment belongs to project, but when I tried to select when there is no payment at all for project it returned nil
or am I missing something?

Comment: right, now I tested it and it works..thanks, I was doing something wrong for the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define a method like to following in your model:

```
# in app/models/project.rb
has_many :payments

def collected_money_percentage
  sum = payments.where(confirmed: true).sum(:amount)
  (100.0 * sum / amount ).round
end
```

Then you cound use that method like this:

```
Project.where('enabled = true and enddate > ?', Time.now)
       .sort_by(&:collected_money_percentage)
```

Please note that this first loads all matching record and then calculations the `percentage` in memory. It would probably be faster to calculate this values in your database:

```
Project.joins(:payments)
  .where('enabled = true and enddate > ?', Time.now)
  .group('projects.id')
  .order('SUM(payments.amount) / projects.amount')
```

Comment: thanks, that first option using custom function works fine..
second option looks it works ok but ordering is wrong
I've added there condition to where (and payments.confirmed = true) to work only with confirmed payments but didnt help